# Date formatting not working properly

Tags: apex, datetime, date, system

I have my locale set at (GMT-05:00) Central Daylight Time (America/Chicago). And I am using the below Apex.

```
DateTime d2 = System.Today() ;
system.debug('date is '+d2); // date is 2021-04-10 00:00:00
String dateStr1 =  d2.format('MM/dd/yyyy') ;
system.debug('formatted date is '+datestr1); // formatted date is 04/09/2021
```

**Why is the date changing before and after formatting?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Format (yyyy/MM/DD)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/290153/62544)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `System.debug` outputs the original DateTime value as GMT, but when you use `DateTime.format(formatStr)`, it is rendered in the user's time zone. If the user is West of GMT-00:00, the day will still be the previous day compared to GMT, so the day is lost. Use `DateTime.formatGMT(formatStr)` if you want the same output as `System.debug`.